# Problem formatting NSDate & NSString while using GData-Objectivec-client

Tags: objective-c, formatting, nsdate, gdata, nsformatter

I'm fighting with a strange situation: same code works different in two different projects. The one project is just empty command line utility with this code. The second project is with linked gdata-objectivec-client library.

Here is the code:

```
static NSString * const dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
NSString *tmp_string = @"03/08/2011 10:07:36 +0300";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease] ;    
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: dateFormat ];

NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: tmp_string];
NSLog(@"dateFromThatString: %@", newDate);
```

In just command line utility the result is same

> "03/08/2011 10:07:36 +0300"

.

But in the project with gdata-objectivec-client linked to it, the result is changed to

> "03/08/2011 07:07:36 +0000"

I cant find what's the problem, any suggestions?

Comment: It might be worth checking the `formatterBehavior` property of your `dateFormatter` to see if it's the same.

Comment: i've checked this property, in both cases it has 0x410 value.

Comment: may be resulting newDate object is the same, and the problem is just with my NSLog? may be it asks a different description of NSDate, if i do ask a desctiptionWithLocale:, then it give's right time with a text description of my location, but i don't like result, becouse i want just the same string, like it was in input, i want location to be represented in +-HHHH, but not in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading about this subject i've learned that "NSDate is not aware of time zones, it always stores dates in a time zone independent manner (as a span of time since a specific reference date)", so those two NSDate objects representing two different strings in two different projects are the same, there is just some problem in difference between description of NSDate objects, so.. it's not a big problem for future work, because i needed these description only for an easy debug. I will just not use description method, but [NSFormatted stringFromDate:].

It's interesting how gdata-objectivec-client influenced on a project, that description of nsdate obj returns same time, but responding to +0000 gmt offset.

But it's only for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the date formatter has different time zones in each case. You can change the time zone using [`-[NSDateFormatter setTimeZone:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).